# Note: MainActivity uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> **My Goal:** To fix this error and be able to run my app without an error.

> **Error Message:** Note:
> D:\Learning\app\src\main\java\com\example\learning\MainActivity.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details.

I get the following error in 'Build Output'. I tried to fix this problem, but every try was unsuccessful. I found some questions related to this error on Stackoverflow, but it didn't meet my needs, so I decided to ask my own question in hope if someone can help me with this error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
String currentPhotoPath;
Button sendBtn;
EditText nameText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    sendBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

}

public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(){
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
        //dispaly error
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    //Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = " JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg",   /* suffix */
            storageDir     /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

public void onClick(View view){

    dispatchTakePictureIntent();

}


public void onClick2(View view) {

    SqlAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlAdapter();

    try {
        Connection con = sqlAdapter.connectionclass();
        String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Test(text) VALUES ('" + nameText.getText().toString() + "') ";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlException){
        Log.e("ERROR", sqlException.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivityForResult(…)` is deprecated in AndroidX activity (`AppCompatActivity`).

They created a replacement named `registerForActivityResult(…)` in `ComponentActivity` (base-base class of `AppCompatActivity`) which should be better.

See [my answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68365615/11958566) and [documentation for `registerForActivityResult(…)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,O%3E,androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)).